# Can Justin.tv's Broadcaster API be used on Android or iPhone?

Tags: mobile, streaming, video-streaming, real-time, mobile-phones

[Justin.tv's Broadcaster API](http://apiwiki.justin.tv/mediawiki/index.php/Broadcaster_API) is Flash-based. Can this be used on Android or iPhone instead of a traditional computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is Flash-based and closed enough to not have a facility for grabbing the video file itself, so that pretty much rules out its use in this situation. However, for the Android phones that have Flash (some do), this Flash-based player API may work.